# Passing data from constructor to member function

Tags: c++, class, c++11, constructor, member-functions

I am trying to write a class that do `matrix` multiplication. The
class `matrix` declared like below:

```
class matrix
{
public:
    vector<vector<int> > M;

    matrix();
    matrix(int m, int n);
    matrix(vector<vector<int> > &m);
    matrix Mul(matrix m1);
    void Inverse();
    bool SquareMatrix();
    void GetDet();
    int Det(vector<vector<int> > &m);
    void Print();
};
```

I initialize and enter the elements of the matrix `M` in this constructor:

```
matrix::matrix(int m, int n)
{
    vector<vector<int> > M(m, vector<int>(n, 0));
    cout << "Enter the elements: " << endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
        {
            cin >> M[i][j];
        }
    }
}
```

However, the member function "Mul" do not receive the data I input through the constructor.

```
matrix matrix::Mul(matrix m1)
{
    int **ppInt;
    ppInt = new int *[M.size()];
    for (int i = 0; i < M.size(); i++)
    {
        ppInt[i] = new int[m1.M[0].size()];
    }

    if (M[0].size() != m1.M.size())
    {
        cout << "Cannot do multiplication!" << endl;
        return matrix();
    }
    else
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < M.size(); i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < m1.M[0].size(); j++)
            {
                int ele_buf = 0;
                for (int k = 0; k < M[0].size(); k++)
                {
                    ele_buf += M[i][k] * m1.M[k][j];
                }
                ppInt[i][j] = ele_buf;
            }
        }
    }
    int d1 = M.size(), d2 = m1.M[0].size();

    for (int i = 0; i < M.size(); i++)
    {
        M[i].clear();
    }
    M.clear();

    for (int i = 0; i < d1; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < d2; j++)
        {
            M[i][j] = ppInt[i][j];
        }
    }
}
```

How can I fix it?

Please let me know if my problem is not clear enough.

Comment: Try `M = vector<vector<int> >(m, vector<int>(n, 0));` in ctor

Comment: Think about this. In your code you declare `M` twice. Once in the class, and once in the constructor. Don't you think that you should only need to declare something once? Remove the declaration in the constructor, you only need the declaration in the class.

Comment: Another thing to think about (but not what you actually asked about). In your code you've shown you know how to use a vector. but in your `matrix::Mul` method you are using pointers for `ppInt`. Why did you do that? If a vector is best for `M` why is it not also best for `ppInt`? Your use of pointers in `matrix::Mul` is actually bugged because you have a memory leak. Change `matrix::Mul` so that `ppInt` is a vector, that will fix the memory leak, and also result in simpler code.

Comment: When your matrix object is created, so is your data vector M. The constructor should not re-declare M, just a re-size will do. The vector you now declare will not be part of the class but since there is already a `(*this)->M`, I'm amazed that it compiles.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I initialize and enter the elements of the matrix `M` in this
> constructor!

No! You are working with a local `M`, not with the member `M`.

In the constructor

```
matrix::matrix(int m, int n)
{
    vector<vector<int> > M(m, vector<int>(n, 0));  // local to the constructor only!
    // .........
}
```

the `M` is local to the scope of the constructor, which [shadows the member you defined with the same name `M`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing).  Therefore it (i.e the one in the constructor)  will be destroyed after the constructor scope. In effect, the member `M` will never get initialized.

---

> How can I fix it?

In order to fix, you might want to [`std::vector::resize`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/resize) the member `M`

```
matrix(int m, int n)
{
   M.resize(m, vector<int>(n, 0)); // resize M with `m` and `n`
   std::cout << "Enter the elements: " << std::endl;

   for (std::vector<int>& row : M)
      for (int& ele : row)
         std::cin >> ele;  // fill the elements
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> I initialize and enter the elements of the matrix M in this constructor:

No you don't. You are initializing a vector called `M` that shadows the member with the same name. The `M` in the constructor is a different vector that is local to the constructor.

To initialize members, use the initializer list:

```
matrix::matrix(int m, int n) : M(m, vector<int>(n, 0)) {
cout << "Enter the elements: " << endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
        {
            cin >> M[i][j];
        }
    }
}
```